# Decimal não está aceitando casas decimais - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, visual-studio, decimal

Estou realizando um projeto em ASP.NET, porém começou a dar um problema, o campo só aceita receber números inteiros, toda vez que eu coloco um número decimal, por exemplo `20.10`, ele simplesmente não deixa eu inserir o Produto. Na classe ele está como nome de `precoUnitario` e `decimal`.

Segue a Classe:

```
public class Produto
{
    private ConexaoDB db;

    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 5 caracteres")]
    [Key]
    public string idProduto { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 50 caracteres")]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preço Unitário")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório")]
    public decimal precoUnitario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Categoria")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório")]
    public string idCategoria { get; set; }

    public void InsertProduto(Produto produto)
    {
        string strQuery = string.Format("insert into produto(idProduto, nome, precoUnitario, idCategoria)" +
            "values('{0}', '{1}', {2}, '{3}');", produto.idProduto, produto.nome, produto.precoUnitario, produto.idCategoria);

        using (db = new ConexaoDB())
        {
            db.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

O Projeto também está conectado ao banco, segue a tabela Produto:

```
CREATE TABLE produto(
idProduto varchar(5) primary key,
nome varchar(50) not null,
precoUnitario decimal(10, 2) not null,
idCategoria varchar(5) not null,
foreign key (idCategoria) references categoria(idCategoria)
 );
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Existe algum erro? Qual? Onde ele ocorre? Qual o valor que é adicionado à query (em `strQuery`)? Não havendo erro, é inserido algum valor ao usar "20.1"? E com "20,1", o que ocorre?

Comment: Na caixa tem que digitar no formato brasileiro pelo visto `20,10` com virgula e o próprio algoritmo faz o trabalho pesado pra ti, inclusive, esses nomes estão fora do padrão que as inicial e principais de um nome são escrito em maiusculo (isso não é Java é C#) então `PrecoUnitario` seria um exemplo de como escrever nomes em C#

Comment: @Leo Por acaso em em algum momento, você não realizando alguma operação matemática com esse valor utilizando um número inteiro? Tipo, alguma soma ou multiplicação?